# XML serialization - build a list of child elements of a certain type

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am brand new (day 2) to c# so I apologize ahead of time if my terminology is a bit off.

Consider the following XML and class models:

```
<Page label="Page 1.1">
    <Group label="Group 1.1.1"></Group>
    <Group label="Group 1.1.2"></Group>
    <Text label="Text 1.1.1"></Text>
    <Text label="Text 1.1.2"></Text>
</Page>

public class AbstractElementModel
{
    [XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string label;
}

[Serializable]
public class Page:AbstractElementModel
{
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Group)),
     XmlArrayItem(typeof(Text))]
    public AbstractElementModel[] content;
}
```

**(Group and Text models not shown, for this example they are blank classes extending AbstractElementModel)**

I would like to be able to push any instances of Group or Text into the content list. However, when the XML document is deserialized content is null. I did notice that it works if I structure the XML as follows:

```
<Page label="Page 1.1">
    <content>
        <Group label="Group 1.1.1"></Group>
        <Group label="Group 1.1.2"></Group>
        <Text label="Text 1.1.1"></Text>
        <Text label="Text 1.1.2"></Text>
    </content>
</Page>
```

However, I need to be able to deseralize the XML structure as shown in the first example.

What is the best way to acomplish this?

Thanks for your time!

*edit*

Updated XML structure to make the problem clearer.

Comment: One thing you did not mention is how many Group and Text nodes can be a child of Page. Your example implies they can occur only once.

Comment: Yes good point. I updated the original post to contain multiple elements for each type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz6bdh5z.aspx) if you don't want a wrapper element:

```
public class Page:AbstractElementModel
{
    [XmlElement("Group", typeof(Group))]
    [XmlElement("Text", typeof(Text))]
    public AbstractElementModel[] content;
}
```

other notes:

- you don't need `[Serializable]`
- public fields are generally not recommended - a property would be preferred
- IMO a list would be better than an array here

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! And thank you for the additional notes. The public fields were just for brevity in the example, but I will certainly make the other changes you mentioned. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to keep the original order of elements?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you may have multipule nodes of the same type under Page this should work.

```
[Serializable]
public class Page:AbstractElementModel
{
    [XmlArrayItem()]
    public Group[] Group;
    [XmlArrayItem()]
    public Text[] Text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear on that. It needs to be pushed into a single list to conform to an external API. I suppose if that was the only option, I could create getters/setters for every type of element and manually populate the content list. There are a lot of different element types, so this would not be an ideal solution...

Comment: I assumed that's what you meant to begin with. The same problem applies. I need a single list that contains all child elements. Is there no way to do this using serialization?

Comment: @dkrstr yes there is; simply, via a different attribute (have added as an answer)